# How to go from an episodic task to a continuing one

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, temporal-difference

I have implemented a Q-Learning algorithm for an episodic undiscounted (i.e. discount factor = 1) task. The task is to escape from a predator, so the way I have implemented it now is to set a maximum number of timesteps, after which the agent is considered "escaped" and given a positive reward. If the agent is caught before the end of the episode, a negative reward is given. At each time step, the reward is zero.

I would like to change from this episodic definition to a continuing definition of the same problem, where there is no maximum number of timesteps. However, the "episode" can still end at some point, if the agent is captured by the predator.

In [Sutton & Barto's book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf) I found something, but I am a little confused... in the first few chapters it only says that you have to consider a *discounted* task (i.e. set a discount factor less than one) to deal with a continuing interaction, but then it doesn't go into detail. Chapter 10.3, on the other hand, talks about the "average reward" approach for *non-discounted* continuing tasks.

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this correctly? Do you know of any articles or books that talk in detail about how to deal with reinforcement learning for a discounted or undiscounted continuing task?

Also: I am familiar with using a linearly decreasing exploration rate (epsilon) in an episodic task. In the case of a continuing task, how do you schedule the epsilon decay?

Comment: How about giving a reward of +1 for every tilmestep where the agent has not been caught and -1 when the agent is caught

Comment: @Lenny1357 I am not sure that would work well, because the impact of getting caught (-1) would decrease as times goes on (since at every timestep the total reward is getting accumulated as +1, +1, +1,...). Don't you think?

Comment: I see your point but to some degree that is by design. Getting caught after 500 steps is a lot better than getting caught after 5. Hence the reward should be higher the longer the agent survives. I think it would work in practice. In the Cartpole environment for example I have made an RL model with the same reward scheme +1 for every step where the pole is not dropped and -1 otherwise. If you want you can try scaling the negative reward as time goes on.